# Explanation of all types of SQL joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering if anyone can break down joins for me in a way other than just posting a visual chart. I know how to use them, but I can't really define them, so really I probably don't have the best knowledge.

The things that trip me up, how do you define INNER/OUTTER vs LEFT/RIGHT in what they do, and when you'd use them? I'm self-taught on joins, are there simple structural definitions that might help make sense of them? I use these frequently enough, but they're still a bit of a gray area to me for the complete picture.

Comment: I know you said more than a visual chart... but this to me is worth it's weight in gold as it breaks them down...http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ and uses sample data to show you what results occur!  (of course. weighing electrons... means it doesn't weigh that much... So I'll just call it invaluable.

Comment: If you use these frequently, I'm not sure how you don't understand them... Left/Right (outer) Join:  Get everything from the table on the left/right of the equal sign in the join clause and only the matches in the table on the opposite side.  Full Outer: Get everything from both sides of the equal sign.  Inner: Get only those where there is a match in both tables

Comment: I was just posting what @xQbert has done, it's what I tell everyone to read when learning SQL

Comment: left/right **is** an outer join.

Comment: haha I've had that printed and sitting on my desk for a few years. I've been building an object oriented data storage system that sits on mysql. I'm currently working on how to define parent child relationships, and didn't really know how to define how joins work in the user interface beyond letting the user try them and see what comes out. I didn't know if there was a better way to define them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requisite reading: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

```
FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID
```

Give me records from both tables but only if they match
This says if A and B both only have ID 1 in common, 1 will be the only record in the result set.

```
FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID.
```

Give me all records from A and those that match from B.  So all 10 records in A and the 1 that matches in B. Still 10 records, unless the same ID exists in each table multiple times. but this usually means the data isn't normalized, or your missing join criteria.

```
FROM A RIGHT JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID
```

Give me all records from B and only those that match from A
 It does the same thing as a left join if you just re-arranged the tables in the from clause.

```
FROM A CROSS JOIN B
```

Give me all records as they relate to all records if both tables have 10 records, your resulting dataset would contain 100 records (10*10)

```
LEFT JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN... same thing
RIGHT JOiN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN ... same thing
JOIN,  INNER JOIN same thing.
```

Select * FROM A, B Older method of doing joins (same as a cross join unless limiting criteria provided in where clause.

Comment: Thanks for breaking that down for me!